# Oracle: How to create a "reverse" index primary key?

Tags: oracle, index, primary-key

I can create a primary key for a table and then reverse it with the command

```
alter index T_PK rebuild reverse online;
```

How can I create it reversed?

Comment: For my own information: why would I want to create a reversed index?

Comment: When the PK is a sequence, it can cause contention when newly added rows all hit the same block.  Reversing the index solves that problem. http://www.orafaq.com/node/2907

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary key index (including index parameters) can be specified with the `using index` clause.  You can include the `reversed` specification there.

```
create table T(X number primary key
                 using index (create unique index T_PK on T(X) reverse));
```

Comment: You probably want index to be unique as well in this case - `.... using index (create unique index ....)`

Comment: I checked that, Oracle will take care of that automatically since it's a primary key.

Comment: @ Mark Harrison: Not exactly.  Unique constraint can be supported by non-unique index (as well as by unique which is default) , but presence of unique constraint does not make index unique . .  You can test it by dropping constraint and keeping index.

Comment: @a1ex07, you're right.  Thanks, and answer updated.